# multiple php if($category->getId()==

Tags: php, if-statement

I show dynamic content depending on category.
The code works perfectly fine, except I would like to combine multiple getId in 1 if statement. Currently every category Id is called per if or elsif statement. Wich gives me a lot of extra code.
Is it possible to combine mulitple category id's  in 1 if statement???

The current code:

```
<?php $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/layer')->getCurrentCategory();?> 
<?php if($category->getId()==1): ?> text 1
<?php elseif($category->getId()==2): ?> text 1
<?php elseif($category->getId()==3): ?> text 1
<?php else: ?> text 2
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: please write a title without code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I usually do this by using the [in_array()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) function. So:

```
<?php
    $myValidIds = array(1,2,3);
    if(in_array($category->getId(), $myValidIds)){
        // Do something....
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple in_array would suffice.

```
$allowed = array('1', '2', '3');
if (inarray($category->getId(), $allowed)){
    //it exists, show text 1
}else{
    //it doesnt exist, show text 2
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not

```
$cat = $category->getId();
if($cat==1) ...
```

?

Answer (score -1):

If "text 1" is provided whenever id equals 1, 2, or 3 why can't you just type

```
<?php if($category->getId()==1 || $category->getId()==2 || $category->getId()==3): ?> text 1
```

?

Comment: This is so ugly and unreadable... And getId() method is called EVERY TIME!

Comment: Well, it works. Besides, as a J2EE programmer i can't find anything ugly in this beautiful 100 signs line;)

Comment: Well, as a PHP programmer I find it ugly